# move_uploaded_file() permission denied, unable to move PHP

Tags: php

I am creating a profile picture upload function for my site, but for some reason, `move_uploaded_file()` does not want to function.

I have tried multiple forums and tested out all the possible different approaches, but with no luck.

Here is my PHP & HTML:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_FILES['avatar'])){
        if(empty($_FILES['avatar']['name'])){
            $errors[] = 'Please select an avatar.';
        } else {
            $ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

            $file       = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
            $fileext    = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
            $filetmp    = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];

            if(in_array($fileext, $ext)){
                $file = md5(microtime() . $filetmp) . '.' . $fileext;
                $filepth = './data/user_data/img/udid/prof/' . $file;
                move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepth);
            } else {
                $errors[] = 'Please select a valid file type. (JPG, JPEG or PNG)';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="avatar-form-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="avatar"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

So first off, I am checking that the selected file has a valid extension, if so, it will hash the file temporary name with the microtime (for security). I am then concatenating the extension onto the end with a full stop between it, i.e the output will be `md5hash.png`.

I am then creating a file path variable by concatenating the file variable onto the end of my directory.

I then proceed with the file upload function by passing through the `$filetmp` and `$filepth` variables (like you're supposed to do).

However, when I go to test this function out on my page, I get these errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(./data/user_data/img/udid/prof/e4d0cde3c9330222ef3ab651fe797bed.jpg):
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/settings.php
on line 40


Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpkWSGLy'
to './data/user_data/img/udid/prof/e4d0cde3c9330222ef3ab651fe797bed.jpg'
in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/settings.php
on line 40
```

This is my current layout:

The settings page (the one where the user uploads there picture) is in the root directory.

The location in which I want to put the avatar is inside of a folder (also in the root directory.

I am currently testing all of this on my MacBook running XAMPP and have made sure that file_uploads is set to "on" in my `php.ini` file.

All help is appreciated. Not sure If I have done this incorrectly, but I am almost certain that I haven't.

**EDIT:**

So, It turns out, that by default on a MacBook (when running XAMPP), all files inside of XAMPP/htdocs are set to read only and you must manually set them to "read & write" to allow `move_uploaded_file` to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have set the proper write permissions for your uploaded images folder in your MacBook.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: Where do you store the uploaded images in your xampp folder? If it is a MacBook right click folder to check file permissions.

Comment: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/` this is the directory of the temp file, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Here are instructions for Yosemite OS X https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18894?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: check my latest edit :)